# Workaround for appearing to change the URL of an infinite scrolling page when pushState is not available due to analytics

Tags: seo, javascript, ajax, crawlable-ajax, infinite-scroll

I'm building a website and they want it to be an infinite scroll single page design, and to be as SEO friendly as possible.

Just to give you an example:

Here is an example URL structure:

> com
>
> com#something
>
> com#something1
>
> com#something2

But here is what the URL structure would look like if it were broken down into individual pages:

> com
>
> com/something
>
> com/something1
>
> com/something2

So, what am I supposed to do here?

I've previously used jQuery's `pushState` functionality. This allows my scrolling page to be segmented into various page-like sections, which can be identified in the SERPs with a unique URL and meta data.

I'm not able to use `pushState` here, because this is a really big page and I need any possible analytics that I can get.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: Isn't parallax a technique for pinning images to the background as the page scrolls down?   I'm not following what it has to do with URLs.

Comment: Yeah, it is. But in navigation menu, links are standing like com#something1, so they can put me on specific part of the page. It's like having let's say 5 pages in one page. You know what I mean or should I make this little bit more clearer in my question?

Comment: I'm concerned in link building and negative impact on SEO. And I need every bit of analytics.

Comment: It sounds like your question is about multiple articles in a single page rather than about parallax.

Comment: Nope, it's different, because of links in navigation menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, parallax is a visual effect. What you're asking about is a single "infinitely" scrolling page, or Single Page Application.

If I'm understanding correctly, you don't want to use `pushState` because you think you'll lose analytic data. I'm not sure why you think that: [Google Analytics describes set-up for SPAs here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications).

That being said, if it's a "really big page" and SEO and analytics are critically important, I'd question whether an SPA is the best approach. Aside from the engineering problems, search engines other than Google still struggle to crawl AJAX and similar configurations. The extent to which you care about that will of course depend on search engine market share inn the market you're operating in.

Unless there's a *highly* compelling, make-or-break user experience argument for SPA, why go to the trouble?

Answer (score 0):

You can push the page-equivalent URL to the client's browse history, not just so they can use the browser's back and forward buttons, but also so each article gets accessed independently by users of a search engine.

However, a search engine like Google is also concerned with duplicate content: if you show the same content on multiple pages (via multiple URLs) then you should declare which page is the leading (canonical) one.

With displaying several articles' contents on the same main page, that may prove difficult.

In that case, I'd suggest looking at solutions to make infinite scroll concepts accessible and SEO-friendly: they push the shown sub page into the browse history.